# How to disable Internet connection over ActiveSync?

Tags: windows-mobile, activesync

I am using standard 3G connection for video streaming. "Streaming Media" application works fine.

However after I connect my WinMo 6.1 device to my laptop, it uses Internet connection over ActiveSync. And my laptop is behind firewall, etc. The video streaming stops working correctly. However I need ActiveSync connection for debugging, file uploads.

How can I force my WinMo 6.1 (HTC) to use 3G / HSDPA for all Internet traffic when having ActiveSync connection open.

Update: "Streaming Media" application is configured to connect via my 3G network.

Update2: At least for my application, calls to ConnMgrMapConRef and ConnMgrEstablishConnectionSync (to choose required connection) solved the problem.

Update3: Some useful [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321531/how-to-open-a-network-connection-from-windows-mobile-with-c#321607) to Connection Manager API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried that out myself, but have a look at [Connection Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416435.aspx). It seems that you can configure an application to use a specific network ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416500.aspx)).

Have a look also at the [Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.aspx) that will allow you to get notifications, when ActiveSync is connected.

If it is only for debugging, I would first try to do it with configuring the phone. Try to change Internet Explorer's connection settings, not to automatically detect network.